# what's the difference let client use certificate which is include private key or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, ssl

Recently I'm using WCF, also **use certificate encrypt the message**.
I search about the WCF certificate example. But I saw there is **two way** to use the certificate for translate the message between server and client.

1. The Server use a certificate which has: **public key + private key**
   The Client use a certificate which has **public key + private key**

   [Here is example generic a public key with private key for server and client both](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF)
2. The Server use a certificate which has **public key + private key**
   The Client use a certificate which has **public key (Only)**

   [Here is example generic a public key and private key to server, and generate a public key only for client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18601/An-easy-way-to-use-certificates-for-WCF-security)

I saw a lot of example, but I still not get it. **Which way is the best?** And **what's the difference the 2 way?** Is there anyone can tell me? Thank you.

PS: I also want to know if client don't has private key, How it encrypt/decrypt the message?

I hope someone can **put some example for this two way**. Because If I'm only use public key in client, it will throw exception : must have the private key.

Comment: you're basically asking how public-key cryptography works...

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I don't very clearly know about certificate encryption. I saw the server has public and private key. but client not, it only has public key.

Answer (score 2):

Consider 2 parties Alice and Bob
 If Alice wants to send Bob data in a secure fashion,

1. Alice just has to encrypt it with Bob’s **public** key,
2. Only Bob can then open the file using his **private** key.

The **public** key can be known by **everyone** and is used by senders for encrypting messages. Messages encrypted with the **public** key can only be decrypted in a reasonable amount of time using the **private** key (which only the reciever holds).

This concept is known as an **Asymmetric Public-Private Key Cryptosystem**

Comment: So what about the client only has public key? how client decrypt the server message?

Comment: @qakmak I don't know if WCF uses it this way, but a common way is the message the client sends to the server is "Use the following random symmetric key I just created for the rest of our communications" then the two sides use that temporary randomly generated key. The certificate is only used in establishing the connection, it is not used for the bulk of the data transfer.

Comment: Still don't understand about client use only public key. Some example said create a ``public + private key`` and a ``public key``, but when I try to use ``public key`` communicate with Server, WCF will throw exception tell me Client don't has ``privat key``

Answer (score 0):

What you should be looking at is **Certificate based Authentication**

A Server/Client  use a Certificate to prove thier **authenticity** (To prove that it not an **imposter**)

Hence if the client has the server's certificate , the server's public key is sufficient to verify the server's authenticity .

For more details look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381975(v=vs.85).aspx

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/ActiveMQ_Security_Guide/files/SSLUseCerts.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/ActiveMQ_Security_Guide/files/X509CertsWhat.html

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257587

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I'm using right or not, after I test , If I use a certificate which only has public key. then the client will throw exception tell me, the certificate must has private key....

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the basic concepts of asymmetric cryptography first of all.

**Encrypting**
For simplicity, think of it this way:

For one party (Alice) to receive a secret message from the other (Bob), Alice must first send Bob a box to put the message in. This box has a special lock that only Alice's key can open. When bob receives the box, it is open. He puts the message in it and closes it. At this point, nobody except Alice can open it any longer.

Now if Alice wanted to send her own message to Bob, she would first have to request a similar box from him - that is his public key.

This means that both parties must have their own private keys, and access to the other parties public key if they are going to communicate securely both ways. You could in theory communicate securely only one way (eg. enable the client to send secure messages to the server by having the client encrypt them with the server's public key).

You can find a lot more info about these things at [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com). See for instance [this excellent and relevant answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20833/42360).

**Signing** 
There is also another side to this: A secret private key can also be used to sign data, which helps to verify the sender. This verification can be done using the public key.

Example:

Bob wants to send Alice a document, and wants to signs it. That basically adds a checksum to the message, which is computed using Bob's private key. When Alice receives the message, she can use Bob's public key to check that the signature is valid. If it is, then this has two significant consequences:

1. Alice can trust that the message is unaltered, as originally sent from bob (and not tampered with by other along the way).
2. Bob can not deny having sent the message (unless someone has stolen his secret key and used it to sign the message).

For a little more technical info, see the [wikipedia article on Digital Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#How_they_work).

I hope this helps clarify things. This can be a complex and confusing area, and it's important to get it right. I think the first link you included is a good example; I recommend you download the code and experiment with it. Make sure you set it up correctly, and ***verify that it does fail*** (as it should!) when you remove the client certificate, and vice versa. That should help you get a good grasp of the basic concepts.

Comment: Thank you, that's really clear. But based your answer: Server and Client ``must have private key``, Am I wrong about client don't need ``private key``?  because I remember a lot of example said create a ``private+public key`` and create ``only public key``. Or, Client can access Server message with ``public key``, But If Server want to access Client, use something like ``Duplex Channel``, then the Client must has ``private key`` too?  But in my test even when the Client only send message to Server, but WCF will throw exception if Client only ``public key``

Answer (score 0):

Obviously  people here could just cut and paste links to docu.
eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx 
But that doesnt answer the give me a 10000 foot understanding of certificates and PKI. There is a chance this question will be closed since it is asking a broad question about security. Btw  security equivalent of Stackoverflow is https://security.stackexchange.com/ and is an awesome site.  A relevant example is https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work

Here is a **simple** explanation.

- Certificates are a way encrypting.
- You can encrypt with a Public Key and Decrypt with a private key and Vice versa.
- You can encrypt the network traffic
   eg SSL Also know as Https
  you have a safe channel/tunnel to send info
- A public key can be issued by a trusted  Authority so the client can verify the certificate is valid. The server is genuine.
- Client certificates are **normally** used for Authentication (logon)
  but note there are different types of certificates and processes.
- Certificates can also be used for important Message encryption.
  Sometimes there is an requirement to also protect at document level.
  Message or document encryption is used by a sender so the receiver can be relatively sure the document is valid and unaltered. Public keys are exchanged to achieve this
- Generally speaking the tool/software that manages the process establishing a certificate on a server or client manages the private key.
- Normally when a Certificate is generated, it is generated for a specific use case.  EG as a SSL certificate or a Logon/Authentication certificate.
  in Windows IIS situation, this may help clarify http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/02/18/client-certificates-v-s-server-certificates.aspx
- If a certificate has been compromised, Server private key or client authentication cert was shared, you can "revoke" the certificate and issue a new one. eg https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754(v=ws.10).aspx

**point 1. in detail** see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67931/why-cant-i-decrypt-ssl-traffic-with-the-clients-private-key-only

**Point 2 Client only Certificate**
This was the client authentication scenario. I dont like the public key analogy here. The cert is effectively a key to logon on. You don't share it publicly. The cert needs to be protected.  The example may appear nice or clever. Post a link on Security exchange and watch them eat it alive. DONT do this in a "real"  scenario.